# sprintf using function as argument

Tags: c

I am stuck on getting a simple string from a c function call of const char* and sprintf function having 10 calls of same function as format argument. But sprintf gives always last same argument value on call of function u ie: "MM"

```
main()
 {
  char test[1000];
  int x=sprintf(test,"%s %s",u(17,0),u(18,1));
  printf(test);
 }

const char *u(int a,int b)
{
 static char retStr[700]; 
 static char retStr1[700]; 
 const char *c;
 char *d[]={"S","M","T","W","F"};
 if(b==0) c="red";
 if(b==1) c="blue";

    if(a==17 && b==0) {
        sprintf(retStr1,"<font color=%s>%s</font>",c,d[0]);
        strcpy(retStr,retStr1);
        return retStr;
        } 
    if(a==18 && b==1) {
        sprintf(retStr1,"<font color=%s>%s</font>",c,d[1]);
        strcpy(retStr,retStr1);
        return retStr;
        } 
   return "";
}
```

Comment: `u(18,)` ? What is this? Please post [mcve], and also describe what this thing is supposed to do.

Comment: Note, tagging this both C and C++ isn't helpful. A C++ solution would just say scrap all this and use `std::string` while a C solution will be very different. So pick which one you want.

Comment: Corrected, C only, code is generating HTML strings. One row containing sprintf with 10 strings arguments with same function and return different string and color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same buffer for both invocations of the function.

You're doing this:

- u(17,0) -> prepare retStr, return this *static variable*
- u(18,?) -> overwrite retStr, return this same *static variable*
- call `sprintf` with two references to the same retStr, which now has the data from u(18,?) in it. *

You need a separate buffer for every invocation of the function.  You can either pass a buffer in `u(a, b, buf)` to strcpy into, or use something like malloc to provide a buffer for each invocation of the function and `free` it when you're done.

```
 main()
 {
  char buf1[500], buf2[500]
  char test[1000];
  int x=sprintf(test,"%s %s",u(17,0,buf1),u(18,?,buf2));
  printf(test);
 }

...
const char *u(int a,int b, char *buf)
{
...
     strcpy(buf,retStr1);
...
     return buf;
}
```

Note, there's a lot of dangerous buffer manipulation here if you overflow the buffers, but show the simplest way to fix the issue.

*: This could happen in reverse.  C does not specify which order the function arguments occur.

Comment: As a side note: There is no guarantee that `u(17,0)` is called before `u(18,?)`. The evaluation order of function parameters is unspecified.

Comment: That's true.  They could be reversed, but they both must occur before sprintf is called. Judging by the purported output, I'm guessing they happened L to R. Added a footnote.

Comment: I will try this. Seems logical, i am not a seasoned, but strange, why main buffer can not append each returned buffer, as in case of literals.

Comment: In C, any functions in arguments must complete before the outer function can complete.  Once you sprintf in your function, you're no longer dealing with literals. If all you were doing was `return "m"` and `return "s"` it would work fine.  But you're not, you're constructing a string in a buffer that you keep reusing.  Fine on it's own, but not if you expect it to stay the same after trying it again.

Comment: As an an aside: there's a bunch of functions in the standard Unix (Posix) C library which suffer from this exact problem, and had to be replaced with extended versions that take buffers.  Compare `strerror` to `strerror_r`. This also falls apart if you use threads and a shared buffer.